# MVC 3 project missing "Add View" and "Add Controller" options

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding

Just lately I discovered in one of my projects that the options for "Add View" and "Add Controller" are missing in the Visual Studio "Add" menu. It has been upgraded in between from MVC 2 to MVC 3. I've just been regoing over all steps as in the release notes and tried different ProjectTypeGuids including the ones I've attained by creating a new MVC project in which the "Add View/Controller" options are available:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>
    {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}
</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

But with no luck. Does anybody have any other suggestions?

Comment: Is your controller file located into a "Controllers" folder ? If you don't have a "Controllers" folder, Visual studio will not recognize that it's a controller...

Comment: Yes they are, just as the views are located in the "Views" folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem, it was because I had the old ProjectTypeGuids commented out above the new ProjectTypeGuids, removing the commented line fixed it.